# Uneven (crooked drywall) next to ceramic

Tags: drywall

[image]We are working on a basement bathroom. And after installing the ceramic we realized the wall is very uneven compared to the straight ceramic. Any idea on how we would even out the drywall? Is compound mud the only solution? Thank you

Comment: Install baseboard of some type (enough to cover the gap) on the wall against the floor. Otherwise that is a lot of mud- but can be done.

Comment: stuff happens, it will men the 2x4 framing was not leveled. Loosen the drywall screws and see it it pops up

Comment: Should have sorted this before laying the tiles - the first straight line showed you the issue.

Comment: Judging by the large hole in the wall, this area will be behind a fixture (toilet with rear exit?) and therefore only examined closely by very drunk people lying on the floor or exceedingly fussy cleaners. As such, perfection is probably optional, but feel free to stress about it and mud for a while (hot mud will be faster for the bulk of it) if you're going to lose sleep over an imperfect section of unexamined wall nobody who has not seen this post will know about.

Comment: It’s actually on the side of the toilet! So pretty visible

Comment: I agree solarmike! Unfortunately I’m not the one who did the work